# error: cp: cannot stat ‘release\\-1.0.0\r.jar’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cp

I have a file "release-1.0.0.jar" in the current working directory, and I'm trying to copy it to a directory "release_dir".

```
export t_version="1.0.0"

mkdir -p release_dir

cp release-${t_version}.jar release_dir
```

error: `cp: cannot stat ‘release\\-1.0.0\r.jar’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Your script was written on a Windows machine, or have aquired DOS line-endings some other way.

This means that each line of the script has an extra carriage return character (`\r`), which in turn means that the variable `t_version` has a value that is actually `1.0.0\r`, and that the directory that you create will actually be called `release_dir\r`, etc.

Convert the script file to a Unix text file using `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix myscript.sh
```

And also delete that erroneously named directory (assuming you use `bash`):

```
rmdir $'release_dir\r'
```

Comment: That explains the `\r`, but why `\\-`?

Comment: @RalfFriedl Unless the user is showing a modified script from what they ran, I can't really explain that. Note that the script as written would also generate two "command not found" errors for the carriage returns on the otherwise empty lines, so we're definitely are not seeing the script that was run.

Comment: I don't criticize your answer, just wondering.

Comment: @RalfFriedl I didn't think you were, just explaining.

Comment: I tried running these commands in redhat7 Linux machine command line terminal, not in windows.                                                                             
export t_version="1.0.0"
mkdir -p release_dir
cp release-${t_version}.jar release_dir                                                                                                                   I also tried your suggessted solution its still giving same error.

Comment: @itgeek Could you please confirm that the commands are in a script file? Was that script file written on a Windows system?

Comment: These are the commands export t_version="1.0.0"

mkdir -p release_dir

cp release-${t_version}.jar release_dir                                                                 
  , it was written in Linux system only.

Comment: @itgeek I know those are the commands. You've been repeating them many times.  It does not explain how a carriage return has snuck into the file at the end of the line setting the variable `t_version`. If this is a script (which I asked whether it was, and you did not reply), try running `dos2unix` on the script file (which I mentioned in my answer).  You can also try `tr -d '\r' <script >newscript` to delete all carriage returns in the script file (creating a new script file called `newscript`).

Comment: I'm just running commands on Linux Command line not using the script. I did try to put them into a script and ran the dos2unix <scritp name>, and still seeing the same issue